# How do I mock a primitive value for a single test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a test that requires the value of `isBanana` to be `false`.

The **test works** (and `isBanana` is `false`) when I mock the function in the top level `index.test.js`. However this breaks other tests (as they require `isBanana` to be `true`).

```
jest.mock("myapp-api-functions", () => {
  console.log(`executing mock function`);
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual("myapp-api-functions"),
    isBanana: false,
  };
});
```

If I move the `jest.mock()` into the body of the test, `isBanana` is `true` and the test doesn't work.

```
    it(`should error when someone tries to use the mock account in production`, async () => {
      jest.mock("myapp-api-functions", () => {
        console.log(`executing mock function`);
        return {
          ...jest.requireActual("myapp-api-functions"),
          isBanana: false,
        };
      });

      ...same test function that previously passed...
    });
```

The mock doesn't work and the test fails.

**How can I mock the primitive value for a single test?**

Comment: Did my answer help? Did you manage to fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Calls to `jest.mock` get hoisted to the top of the code block.

To [avoid this behaviour you can instead use `jest.doMock`](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) e.g.

```
it(`should error when someone tries to use the mock account in 
production`, async () => {
  jest.doMock("myapp-api-functions", () => {
    console.log(`executing mock function`);
    return {
      ...jest.requireActual("myapp-api-functions"),
      isBanana: false,
    };
  });

  // Same test function that previously passed...
});
```

This will allow you to specify mock behaviour for a specific test.